# add an active class to one of my elements and select only the relevant parent

Tags: javascript

In my menu I would like to add an active class to one of my elements: li.nav-item
and this only if the child item: ul.nav-collapse.li has the active class.

for this I made a script that works but it adds the active class to all elements: li.nav-intem

I would like it to select only the relevant parent: li.nav-item
which contains the active class ul.nav-collapse.li.active

JS

```
$('ul.nav-collapse li').each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('li.nav-item').addClass("active");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1">
            <p>My Folder</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu1">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu2">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu2">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu3">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu3">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like something like this

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1">
            <p>My Folder</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu1">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu2">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu2">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu3">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu3">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if current element has class "**active**"

Use closest to get parent element with specific class :
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Then add class to the current element

```js
$('ul.nav-collapse li').each(function() {
  // if current item has class active
  if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    // add class to the current clicked element
    $(this).closest('.nav-item').addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.nav-item.active { border:1px solid red }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

<ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu1">
            <p>My Folder</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu1">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu2">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu2">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder2_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder2_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" href="#submenu3">
            <p>My Folder2</p>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="submenu3">
            <ul class="nav nav-collapse">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="SubFolder3_2">
                        <span class="sub-item">SubFolder3_2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you   !!!  
it work fine !!   
;-)

Comment: Your welcome @PaquitoUman ;) Can you up vote and validate my answer plz ? :)

Comment: sorry i dont know how to validate and vote ... 
:-o